# Detecting features in a stl mesh file

Tags: algorithm, mesh

I have a folder with several thousand meshes in .stl format and I'm trying to search the mesh files for the ones that contain a specific feature. The size of the features I'm searching for is fairly consistent between models but the orientation and location is widely variable.

These files were originally made for 3d-printing so if the feature I'm looking for has a cavity then it might be obscured by support columns that are placed in the .stl file itself.

So I guess the question is this: Is there an algorithm for finding a given triangle arrangement or something close to it in a triangle mesh without knowing its orientation or location? Possibly when it might be obscured?

(The features in question are mostly alignment related e.g. specially shaped indents in the model that are used to line up the parts for a multi-part print, some models have shaped cutout holes that extend through the model for alignment purposes. )

Comment: depends on the feature but I think this is possible ... for surface cavity (canyon) compute angle between nearby triangles and detect if the angle is CW or CCW ... if the winding is concave you found your feature ... then just group such triangles together ...